# Is there any way to add html file dynamically from django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am very new to django. I want to include html file from django admin dashboard. Let me explain a little.

Let, My model is like below

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    fileName= models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

my views.py file

```
def calcView(request):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    filename = myModel.objects.first()
    context = {}
    context['filename'] = filename
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Now i enter filename in as 'anyfile.html'. It already available in template folder.

Now in index.html file how can i it from dashboard. Pseudo code

```
{% include "{{ filename.fileInclude}}" %}
```

Is it possible ?? if yes, how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have done silly mistake in views file. I wrote     filename = Adsense.objects.first()
 in views file. it will be   filename = myModel.objects.first()

Answer (score 0):

instead of `{% include "{{ filename.fileInclude}}" %}`  you should write:
`{% include filename.fileInclude %}` . no need for `{{ }}` neither for `" "`.